# How do I create a bucket in the EU region?

Tags: php, rest, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a bucket on google cloud storage using PHP and REST. I can create the bucket just fine in the US region but cannot seem to create one in the EU region.

Here's what I'm doing -

```
function createBucket($accessToken, $bucket, $region)
{
    $version_header = "x-goog-api-version: 2";
    $project_header = "x-goog-project-id: ".$this->projectID;
    $url = 'https://'.$bucket.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com';
    $timestamp = date("r");
    define('XML_PAYLOAD','<xml version=\'1.0\' ? ><CreateBucketConfiguration><LocationConstraint>'.$region.'</LocationConstraint></CreateBucketConfiguration>');

    $headers = array(
                'Host: '.$bucket.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com',
                'Date: '.$timestamp, 
                $version_header,
                $project_header, 
                'Content-Length: 0',
                'Authorization: OAuth '.$accessToken);

    $c   = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,XML_PAYLOAD);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    $response = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    // split up the response into header and xml body
    list($header, $xml) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
    // tokenize - first token is the status
    $status = strtok($header, "\r\n"); 

    if(stristr($status,"200 OK"))
    {
        //success
        $result = "success";
    }
    else
    {
        //failed
        $result = "fail";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This function works fine for a US bucket but fails in case of EU. I'm making sure that the name generated for the bucket is a unique name (the same pattern works for US buckets).

**edit:** actually the function does not fail, it does create a bucket ... it just creates the bucket in the US region in spite of specifying the EU region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you telling whether it succeeded? gsutil -L?

I just used gsutil to specify a location and dumped the contents of the request with -DD and noticed that the XML document sent in the request body did not include an XML header. Next I tried using curl to formulate the REST request with a similar header-less XML doc and it worked fine for me. Next I tried curl again with the XML header and it failed with this error:

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
>   our published schema.

Can you retry your PHP code without the XML header and see if that helps? If it does, I can file a bug for this.

Comment: Hi Marc,

Yes I'm using gsutil to test bucket creation.

I actually realized that my REST request had a content-length of 0 and I changed that to:

    `strlen(XML_PAYLOAD)`

and I received the exact error that you see:

    `MalformedBucketConfiguration`
    `The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.`

Comment: Should also mention that I received the error for both US and EU regions

Comment: Your XML appears to be missing the opening question mark `<?xml `: `define('XML_PAYLOAD','<xml version=\'1.0\' ? >...` (this is the case [in the doco](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide#specifyinglocations) as well)

Comment: I tried my curl test with the properly formulated <?xml header which resulted in the same XML document parse error so I've just filed a bug report on this.

Comment: p.s. In the meantime, try dropping the XML header - that worked for me.

Comment: @John, I tried it with the proper XML header and it did the same thing - i.e. create the bucket but in the US region in spite of specifying EU in the XML. Thanks for catching that though! :)